# mouse click to bounce a ball in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How to bounce a stable ball using mouse click? Here is the link (http://cssdeck.com/labs/lets-make-a-bouncing-ball-in-html5-canvas) in the  JavaScript section.It bounces without any click just as the execution is begun but it's needed to begin bouncing right after a mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is using jquery ui

```
$(function(){

    //Add bounce effect on Click of the DIV

    $('#bouncy').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'up', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    //Bounce DIV on click of button
    $("#bounce").click(function(){
        $("div").click();
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/k1tykkfy/)

[Reference : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/)